# no content loading after login admin

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I wanted to work on my magento site today and I couldn't get into the admin panel. When I login I get the following screen:

[image: Screen after login]

It looks like it doesn't load the content or something I think. Is someone familiair with this problem?

Thanks in advantage!

Bjorn

Comment: Did you check your php error log?

Comment: Usually it means there is a fatal error.  Did you check the page source code (ctrl+u) ?

Comment: My system.log gives me this: 2015-02-14T18:49:36+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/MDN_ExtensionConflict_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: And my source code isn't black but isn't very long at all

Comment: varien_autoload.php line 93 is the following code:           return include $classFile;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its trying to load the file from includes/src I would say this is likely related to the code compiler.

Try either a) disabling the compiler `php shell/compiler.php disable` or b) recompiling your code `php shell/compiler.php compile`

I would recommend not using the Magento compiler and using php caching instead e.g APC or OPcache

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution. I commented out the lines in includes -> config.php line 28 AND 29. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yea it's definitely the compiler. Normally it's pretty easy to disable the compiler but in this case your Admin is unusable. Luckily there are a few other ways to disable it. If you know SSH that's the fastest. If you don't or your host doesn't give you SSH access, then you could use an alternate method from this blog post on [how to disable the Magento compiler](http://www.snapfast.com/blog/disable-magento-compiler/).

1. Edit the `includes/config.php` and comment out both lines at the end of the file by placing a # in front of them. If your version of Magento is older it might look slightly different:

   ```
   #define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
   #define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
   ```
2. If you're not sure how to use SSH, you can create a simple PHP file to run the proper commands for you. Simply create a php file like `disable_compilation.php` in your web directory (usually `/home/{username}/public_html/` or `/var/www/`) and paste the contents below. After you have the file saved just navigate to the file in your browser and it'll disable the compiler for you by running the SSH command.

   ```
   <?php
   echo system('php shell/compiler.php disable');
   ?>
   ```